# Laravel 5 eloquent many-to-many relationship issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent, relationship

I'm creating a blog using Laravel 5 but I'm having a strange issue with a many-to-many (via pivot table) relationship.
My DB setup is the following:

**posts table:**
id    | bigint  | 20  | PK | Not Null | Auto Increment
title | varchar | 255 | Not Null
body  | text    | Not Null
category_id | bigint | 20 | Not Null
created_at | timestamp | Not Null
updated_at | timestamp | Not Null
published  | boolean | Not Null
deleted_at | timestamp | Not Null

**tags table:**
id | bigint | 20 | PK | Not Null | Auto Increment
name | varchar | 255 | Not Null
created_at | timestamp | Not Null
updated_at | timestamp | Not Null

**post_tag pivot table:**
id | bigint | 20 | PK | Not Null | Auto Increment
post_id | bigint | 20 | Not Null
tag_id | bigint | 20 | Not Null
created_at | timestamp | Not Null
updated_at | timestamp | Not Null

Following are extracted from my models:
**Post**

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

**Tag**

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

Now on the view if I do this:

```
var_dump($post->tags->first()->name);
```

I'm returned the correct tag associated to the post, but obviously the post can have more tags so what I'm trying to do is a for each loop on ***$post->tags***.
Anyway if I try to do it, it seems the result is not usable and the loop never start.
Then I've tried to look at what I'm returned doing this:

```
var_dump($post->tags);
```

And I'm returned the following:

> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#199 (1) {
>   ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(App\Tag)#200 (21) {
>   ["table":protected]=> string(4) "tags" ["fillable":protected]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "name" } ["connection":protected]=> NULL
>   ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=>
>   int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true)
>   ["attributes":protected]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
>   ["name"]=> string(3) "Tag" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-02-25
>   15:26:29" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2015-02-25 15:26:29" }
>   ["original":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=>
>   string(3) "Tag" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-02-25 15:26:29"
>   ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2015-02-25 15:26:29" ["pivot_post_id"]=>
>   string(1) "6" ["pivot_tag_id"]=> string(1) "2" }
>   ["relations":protected]=> array(1) { ["pivot"]=>
>   object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot)#193 (24) {
>   ["parent":protected]=> object(App\Post)#198 (22) {
>   ["table":protected]=> string(5) "posts" ["dates":protected]=> array(1)
>   { [0]=> string(10) "deleted_at" } ["fillable":protected]=> array(4) {
>   [0]=> string(5) "title" [1]=> string(4) "body" [2]=> string(11)
>   "category_id" [3]=> string(9) "published" } ["connection":protected]=>
>   NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=>
>   int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true)
>   ["attributes":protected]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6"
>   ["title"]=> string(4) "Test" ["body"]=> string(24) " Test
>
> " ["category_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["created_at"]=> string(19)
>   "2015-02-25 15:49:20" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2015-02-25
>   15:49:20" ["published"]=> string(1) "1" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL }
>   ["original":protected]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["title"]=>
>   string(4) "Test" ["body"]=> string(24) " Test
>
> " ["category_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["created_at"]=> string(19)
>   "2015-02-25 15:49:20" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2015-02-25
>   15:49:20" ["published"]=> string(1) "1" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL }
>   ["relations":protected]=> array(2) { ["likes"]=>
>   object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#197 (1) {
>   ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } } **["tags"]=> *RECURSION*** }
>   ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) {
>   } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true)
>   ["forceDeleting":protected]=> bool(false) } ["foreignKey":protected]=>
>   string(7) "post_id" ["otherKey":protected]=> string(6) "tag_id"
>   ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> NULL
>   ["table":protected]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["primaryKey":protected]=>
>   string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=>
>   bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=>
>   array(2) { ["post_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["tag_id"]=> string(1) "2" }
>   ["original":protected]=> array(2) { ["post_id"]=> string(1) "6"
>   ["tag_id"]=> string(1) "2" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) {
>   } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0)
>   { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) } }
>   ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) {
>   } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) {
>   } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) }
>   } }

I've highlighted the part that for me is giving me the problem, for some reason it seems it is having some kind of query recursion which I can't understand why it happens.
Any Idea?

Thanks,
Matteo

Comment: Don't know if this can help, anyway my MySQL version is 5.5.41

Comment: Don't ask me why but now it suddenly started to work, I've not done any change to the code and I can't understand what happened. I hope I'll be able to replicate it eventually in order to share it with you all. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the query collection.
You may convert collection to array using `->toArray()` so you can get only the needed data:

```
$post->tags->toArray();
```

Comment: That's not completely working as I'm being returned the first tag on tags table and not actually the one assigned to the post. Also I want the tag class in order to be able to do something like this: $tag->name

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your **autoload_classmap.php** wasn't up to date.

This file is regenerated on each dump-autoload. If you have a new class somewhere in your project it will not be loaded unless it is included in autoload_classmap

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This may happened to you, maybe automatically by installing or updating package or something.

Good tip: If you face a problem in Laravel, try to run composer `dump-autoload`, which often may fix some problems.